# jQuery Event Delegation Not Working for Dropdown

Tags: jquery

HTML looks as follows:

```
<div id = 'forecastItems'>
  <select class="ui dropdown categoryScopeItem" id = 'categoryScopeItem1' name = updated[forecastID]>
    <option value=""></option>
    <% items.forEach(function(item) { %>
      <option value = '<%= item.key %>' revenue = '<%= item.totalRevenue %>' releasedValue = '<%= item.releasedvalue %>' percentRemaining = '<%= item.percentRemaining %>' remainingToBill = '<%= item.totalRemaining %>' label = '<%= item.jobNumber %>' style = 'display: none'><%= item.item %></option>
    <% }) %>
  </select>
  <br>
  <div class = 'ui left icon input itemValue' style = 'width: 125px'>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" name = updated[value] class = 'ui mini input'>
    <i class = 'dollar sign icon'></i>
  </div>
  <button type = 'button' class = 'newForecastToggle' id = 'firstAdd' style = 'font-size: .8em'>Add More</button>
  <div style = 'display: inline'>
    <span class = 'forecastInfo'></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = 'holder'>
  <br>
</div>
```

My first event delegation is working correctly:

```
$('#scopeItems').on('click', '.newForecastToggle', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#forecastItems').clone().insertBefore($('#holder'))
});
```

My second event delegation, however, is not working correctly so is only working on the first dropdown:

```
$('#forecastItems').on('change', 'select', function(e) {
  var itemRevenue = $('.categoryScopeItem :selected').attr('revenue')
  var remainingToBill = $('.categoryScopeItem :selected').attr('remainingToBill')
  var percentRemaining = $('.categoryScopeItem :selected').attr('percentRemaining')
  var releasedValue = $('.categoryScopeItem :selected').attr('releasedValue')

  var selectedItem = $(this).next().next().find('input')
  var valueInfo = $(this).next().next().next().next()

  valueInfo.find('.forecastInfo').text('$' + remainingToBill + ' / $' + itemRevenue + ' (' + percentRemaining + '%) Remaining')

  selectedItem.attr('placeholder', remainingToBill)
})
```

I thought perhaps I needed to change #forecastItems to the id for the parent element, but the results are the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Event delegation only works on elements that exist when you create the delegations.  So if you are dynamically creating forecastItems, which it looks like you are in the first delegate, then you are binding too low.

Comment: It's working correctly on the first dropdown, but none of the others so I believe the logic is correct. If you're seeing something I'm not, though, that would be awesome.

Comment: Also as a side note, you are cloning an element with an id, and not changing the id.  That's creating elements with duplicate ids, which is invalid by web standards.

Comment: By 'binding too low' shouldn't changing the reference to #forecastItems to the parent div ID take care of that? Or do I need to do something different? Tried it on document.body and same results.

Comment: It needs to be on something that is not dynamically created.  If you can find an element lower than the document.body that it will work on, do so.  You want it to be as low as possible, but not on something dynamically created.

Comment: Are you saying you changed `$('#forecastItems').on('change', 'select', function(e) {` to `$(document.body).on('change', 'select', function(e) {`  and it did not work?

Comment: Looks like the ID problem you mentioned is part of the issue. Many thanks to both of you for your quick responses. I don't have this solved yet but I'm already making progress!

Comment: And yes, changing to document.body didn't work, which i thought strange.

Comment: If changing it to document.body like that did not cause that event handler to execute, then that would point to some other issue that is not apparent to me at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change:

```
$('.categoryScopeItem :selected').attr('revenue')
```

to

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr('revenue')
```

Thanks to everyone for the input as you helped me get to the solution.